# Run Maxima on iOS Without Rejection From The App Store?

Tags: ios, app-store, appstore-approval, maxima

Is there a way to run maxima on iOS?

I know running another binary is grounds for rejection, so is there a way to not have to start another binary? Or is there another library that can do what maxima can do? I need `factor()`, `expand()`, `diff()` and `ratsimp()`. Or is this impossible?

I have not tried to do this with the exception of doing a little googling, because I am not a super advanced at iOS Development, so I have no idea how to go about this.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

There are 3 considerations:
- you can include "open source" software provided you don't charge for it
- "reduce" is built in to another app; as both rely on LISP for the actual work, I would think that you can if they can
- there is (or was) a rule that you cannot include your own interpreter, but if the app I mentioned above can do it then you probably can on the basis that the user cannot run LISP directly but only through your interface
Of course, these are my personal opinions and comments - you really need to try it out with Apple.
Susan